# How to obtain the Table A rows that are not present in Table B with GORM without using an inList closure?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I have a domain definition which generates the following example for database table:

[image: Table example]

I want to do the following query: **Obtain all domain objects related to *Table A* that are not present in *Table B***

I was using the `inList` closure as follow:

```
    List<DMiembro> m = DMiembro.list()

    List<DUsuario> usuarios = DUsuario.createCriteria().list(params) {
        if (m) {
            not {
                m*.usuario.id.collate(1000).each { def lista ->
                    or {
                        inList("id", lista)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        eq("enabled", true)
        order("nombre", "asc")
    } as List<DUsuario>
```

This works fine. However, data in `DMiembro` is growing to big. Now I am getting a database error related to the size of the query. And that's logical, because the number of parameters of the query is too large

So, is there another way to build a query for gathering `Dusuario` objects that are not present in `DMiembro`?

Comment: i think you should be able to use right-join with a where constraint where the tableB.id IS NULL.

Comment: I tried to use JoinType.RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN. However, I am using Oracle 12c and that syntax is not allowed. I got a message suggeting me the use of Oracle 9i and Oracle 10g diaclect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** 
You can use GORM `DetachedCriteria` inside your criteria.

```
import grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria
List<DUsuario> usuarios = DUsuario.createCriteria().list(params) {
      not {
          'in'('id', new DetachedCriteria(DMiembro).build {
               projections {
                   property 'id'
               }
           })
      }
      eq("enabled", true)
      order("nombre", "asc")
} as List<DUsuario>
```

As you can see, this will be a *NOT IN* SQL request, which isn't a good idea for performances. However, the request is more "understandable" and is still a good solution, no matter the volumetry (except for the request's execution time).

**Solution 2:**
Avoid the NOT IN operator with a `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` and a `NULL` check on DMiembro table. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028030/avoid-sql-where-not-in-clause) for a solution with a left join as plain SQL.

Comment: I am implementing the 2nd option. In my case Dmiembro increase according another table.